# SUM of a SUM in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've this report
[image]

1. Here I make the first sum because I've grouped values from each month (months are "Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo" etc etc.). These values are hidden, but anyway I get the sum and I display the sum for each month.
2. Then I should make the second sum that use values for each month and display the total for each category. Categories are "TOTALE LAVORI RESTAURO", "TOTALE LAVORI EDILE" etc.)
3. This is the final sum, where I sum values from each category.

Everything is working well, but now I have to add a "month" parameter to the report that returns sums until a selected month. This parameter changes the sum 1 with this expression:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!mese.Value <= Parameters!mese.Value, Fields!costi.Value, 0))
```

Now, how should I change expression in SUM2 and SUM3 to work with this parameter?

If I copy that code, ther returns `#Error` and as far as I know I can't use ReportItems sum.

So any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUM #1 could remain `Sum(Fields!costi.Value`) because you need to display every months.
i.e.: display GIUGNO even if `Parameters!mese.Value = 4` (APRILE).

So you have only to change SUM #2 and #3 because TOTALE LAVORI RESTAURO and TOTALI must show only costi from GENNAIO to `Parameters!mese.Value`; i.e. if `Parameters!mese.Value = 4` display only GENNAIO-APRILE even if we have details about GIUGNO.

The expression gave error because you have NULL value in `Fields!costi.Value` or `Fields!mese.Value`: convert this value to zero in your DataSet and you won't have problems.

Comment: I can't do that because I've a request to continue show values for each month even if they are over the parameter. Only the sum has to sum values until the selected month. I explained this in another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679240/partial-sum-in-ssrs-2008-r2/24707070#24707070

Comment: So SUM #1 could remain Sum(Fields!costi.Value) because you need to display Giugno even if Parameters!mese.Value = 4 (Aprile); is it correct?

Comment: Yes It's correct. So that expression should be used in SUM2?

Comment: Yes, in SUM #2 and #3 because TOTALE LAVORI RESTAURO and TOTALI must show only costi from GENNAIO-APRILE (if Parameters!mese.Value = 4) even if we have details about GIUGNO; is it correct? But this expression doesn't work in SUM #2 and #3... so we have to find a solution! how did you group your data?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. And it is correct that this expression doesn't work in SUM #2 and SUM #3, because I receive #Error. Grouping expression for "TOTALE LAVORI RESTAURO" is here http://pastebin.com/9srntUC7 instead SUM #3 grouping expression is here http://pastebin.com/YPcwjXxy

Comment: Current (working) expressions for SUM #1, SUM #2 and SUM #3? Single Table/DataSet? No subreport?

Comment: At the moment all is working with `=Sum(Fields!costi.Value)` for each SUM, then groups make the rest. Single table. Single dataset, no subreport.

Comment: Ok, this is correct: grouping must work like this! So maybe there is a problem on some Fields!costi.value (NULL?). Try something like this to test NULL case: =Sum(IIf(Fields!mese.Value <= Parameters!mese.Value, 100, 0))

Comment: That works. Yes, I can have NULL value or just month without value

Comment: answer completely rewritten. ;)